JWT Token Malformed Error Upon Page Refresh After Successful Login
I have implemented JWT session management using a JWT strategy in my application. However, I'm encountering an issue where after successful login, when I refresh the page, I get redirected to the homepage and receive a "jwt malformed" error.
Could someone please help me identify why my token is being malformed upon page refresh after successful login? Thank you for your assistance.
I've tried placing logs everywhere, but I can't figure out why my token is malformed. Here's the relevant code:
passportJwtStrategie.config.js :
const JwtStrategy = require('passport-jwt').Strategy;
const ExtractJwt = require('passport-jwt').ExtractJwt;
require("dotenv").config({ path: '../../.env' });;
const db = require('../config/db')

const options = {
    jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
    secretOrKey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    algorithms: ['HS256']
};



const configureJwtStrategy = (passport) => {
    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(options, async (jwt_payload, done) =>{
        try {
            let userTable = {
                admin: 'admin',
                veterinarian: 'veterinarian',
                employee: 'employee'
            }[jwt_payload.role];

            const query = `SELECT * FROM ${userTable} WHERE ${userTable}_id = $1`;
            const { rows } = await db.query(query, [jwt_payload.sub]);
            
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                return done(null, rows[0]);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }

        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
            return done(err, false);
        }
    }));
};

module.exports = configureJwtStrategy;

api.login.js :
const express = require("express");
const loginRouter = express.Router();
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");
const bcrypt = require("bcrypt");
const db = require("../config/db");

loginRouter.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, userType } = req.body;
  try {
    let tableMap = {
      admin: { table: "admin", idColumn: "admin_id" },
      veterinarian: { table: "veterinarian", idColumn: "veterinarian_id" },
      employee: { table: "employee", idColumn: "employee_id" },
    };

    let userTable = tableMap[userType];

    const query = `SELECT * FROM ${userTable.table} WHERE email = $1`;
    const { rows } = await db.query(query, [email]);

    if (rows.length === 0) {
      return res.status(404).send("User not found.");
    }

    const user = rows[0];
    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);
    if (!isMatch) {
      return res.status(400).send("Incorrect Password.");
    }

    const payload = {
      sub: user[userTable.idColumn],
      role: userType,
    };

    const token = jwt.sign(payload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "2h",
      algorithm: 'HS256'
    });

    
    res.cookie('token', token, {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: false, 
      maxAge: 2 * 60 * 60 * 1000
    });

    switch (userType) {
      case "admin":
        res.redirect("/admin/dashboard");
        break;
      case "veterinarian":
        res.redirect("/veterinarian/dashboard");
        break;
      case "employee":
        res.redirect("/employee/dashboard");
        break;
      default:
        res.redirect("/");
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send("Internal server error !");
  }
});

module.exports = loginRouter;

autorisation.middleware.js :
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config( { path: '../../../.env'} )

//middleware who check if user authenticated
function checkAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    console.log("Raw cookie header:", req.headers.cookie);  // Log the raw cookie header
    const token = req.cookies.token;
    console.log("Token from cookie-------------------------------------------------------->", token);

    if (!token) {
        console.log("No token found, redirecting to login.");
        return res.redirect('/accueil');
    }

    try {
        const decoded = jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET);
        console.log("Token from decoded--------------------------------------------------->", decoded);
        req.user = decoded;
        next();
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error verifying token: ", err.message);
        res.redirect('/accueil');
    }
}


//middleware who check each role before redirection
function checkRole(role) {
    return (req, res, next) => {
        if (req.user && req.user.role === role) {
            next();
        } else {
            res.redirect('/accueil'); 
        }
    };
}

module.exports = { checkAuthenticated, checkRole };

app.js :
const express = require('express');
const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session')
require('dotenv').config()

const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const strategy = require('./src/config/passportJwtStrategie.config')

const app = express();
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.use(passport.initialize());

app.use(cookieParser());

app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SECRET,
    name: "token",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: { secure: false }
}));

strategy(passport)
app.use(express.json());

app.use(helmet())
app.use(morgan('tiny'));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.set("views", path.join(__dirname, "src", "views"));

module.exports = app

server.js :
const https = require("https");
const fs = require('fs');
const app = require("./app");
const path = require('path')
require("dotenv").config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT;

//web site pages routes
const accueilRouter = require('./src/routes/home/accueil.routes');
const serviceRouter = require('./src/routes/services/services.routes');
const habitatRouter = require('./src/routes/habitats/habitats.routes');
const contactRouter = require('./src/routes/contact/contact.routes');
const adminDashboardRouter = require('./src/routes/dashboard/adminDash.routes');
const employeeDashboardRouter = require('./src/routes/dashboard/employeeDash.routes');
const veterinarianDashboardRouter = require('./src/routes/dashboard/veterinarianDash.routes');

//Api routes
const foodAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/food/foodAPI.routes');
const serviceAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/services/serviceAPI.routes');
const habitatAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/habitat/habitatAPI.routes');
const consommationAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/consommation/consommationAPI.routes');
const animalAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/animal/animalAPI.routes');
const healthRecordAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/healthRecord/healthRecordAPI.routes');
const visitorReviewAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/visitorReview/visitorReview.routes');
const manageEmployeeAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/employee/manageEmployeeAPI.routes');
const manageVeterinarianAPIRouter = require('./src/api/v1/veterinarian/manageVeterinarianAPI.routes');

//login & logout router
const loginRouter = require('./src/auth/api.login');
const logoutRouter = require('./src/auth/api.logout');


//define website principales routes
app.use('/accueil', accueilRouter, loginRouter);
app.use('/services', serviceRouter);
app.use('/habitats', habitatRouter);
app.use('/contact', contactRouter);
app.use('/admin', adminDashboardRouter, logoutRouter);
app.use('/employee', employeeDashboardRouter, logoutRouter);
app.use('/veterinarian', veterinarianDashboardRouter, logoutRouter);

//Arcadia API
app.use('/api/v1/services', serviceAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/foods', foodAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/habitats', habitatAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/consommation', consommationAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/animal', animalAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/healthRecord', healthRecordAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/visitorReview', visitorReviewAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/manageEmployeeAccount', manageEmployeeAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/v1/manageVetrinarianAccount', manageVeterinarianAPIRouter);
app.use('/api/login', loginRouter);


//https options
const options = {
  key: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./certificates/localhost+2-key.pem")),
  cert: fs.readFileSync(path.join(__dirname, "./certificates/localhost+2.pem")),
};

const server = https.createServer(options,app);
server.listen(PORT, async () => {
  console.log(`You are listening to port ${PORT}`);
});

Error that appears in my logs :
POST /accueil 302 76 - 174.770 ms
Raw cookie header: token=eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTcxNTI1ODgzMywiZXhwIjoxNzE1MjY2MDMzfQ.C-Zz6wVMksp_Nkye3F3-8Q8b1wRlYxYR0AOQUIr0PQ0
Token from cookie-------------------------------------------------------> eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJzdWIiOjEsInJvbGUiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTcxNTI1ODgzMywiZXhwIjoxNzE1MjY2MDMzfQ.C-Zz6wVMksp_Nkye3F3-8Q8b1wRlYxYR0AOQUIr0PQ0
Token from decoded---------------------------------------------------> { sub: 1, role: 'admin', iat: 1715258833, exp: 1715266033 }
GET /admin/dashboard 200 14132 - 10.968 ms
GET /css/style.css 304 - - 0.749 ms
GET /images/Arcadia-logo.png 304 - - 2.797 ms
GET /css/home.css 404 151 - 3.304 ms
Raw cookie header: token=s%3AEKtTbyjLaLmtXIsFIaxRKUxTBdNXM6HF.ynt6l%2BNQRkjziK3JaccZwyNXvmYZxjpfDPOaF%2B6Gh%2BU
Token from cookie--------------------------------------------------------> s:EKtTbyjLaLmtXIsFIaxRKUxTBdNXM6HF.ynt6l+NQRkjziK3JaccZwyNXvmYZxjpfDPOaF+6Gh+U  
Error verifying token:  jwt malformed

